# How to write the SQL query for a search having to consider several values using php?

Tags: php, postgresql

On my page, I have text boxes and drop down lists.
All the values are stored in arrays.
I want to fetch values of year from the database vehicles.
Below shows the html code.

```
<form name="frm_vehicles" action="processinput.php" method ="post">                                 
                                    Enter year of vehicle
                                    <input type="text" name="year[]" >


                                        <select name="choice[]">
                                            <option value="cars" selected="selected">Cars</option>
                                            <option value="lorry">Lorry</option>
                                        </select>



                                        <select name="query[]">
                                            <option value="and" selected="selected">AND</option>
                                            <option value="or">OR</option>
                                            <option value="not">NOT</option>
                                        </select>

                                    <br> 

                                    <input type="text" name="year[]">

                                    <br>
                                        <select name="choice[]">
                                            <option value="cars" selected="selected">Cars</option>
                                            <option value="lorry">Lorry</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <div id="disp"></div>
                                        <input type="button" name="addRow" onclick= "addRow()">
                                        <input type="button" type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>
```

On clicking the button addRow, a javasccript function is called and another row is added. The elemets below are added.

```
                            <input type="text" name="year[]" >


                                <select name="choice[]">
                                    <option value="cars" selected="selected">Cars</option>
                                    <option value="lorry">Lorry</option>
                                </select>
```

Thus, we can see that the fields are dynamically added.

When all fields have been selected, the input are sent to the processinput.php file.
In this file, SQL statements are written.
What should happen is a statement should be executed based on the user's input.
Cars and Lorry are two different tables

The and/or/not are used as joins.
If 'and' is selected, both value of the previous year entered and the value after should match.
If 'or' is selected, only one value may match.
If 'not' is selected, the values after the 'not' is not selected.
So what need to be done is to write a SQL statement to take the values and perform the search.

For example
I add a third row. 
i entered 2006 in first text box and selected table 'cars' and 'and'
in the 2nd row, i entered year selected table 'lorry' and 'not'
in the third row i entered table 'year' and 'cars'

> $year=$_POST['year'],  $choice=$_POST['choice'], 
>   $query=$_POST['query']

Can someone guide me how to write a single sql statement.

How will i mention the $year, $choice and $query in my sql statements?
Should i use a loop ?

Choice will have either tables cars or lorries.

Cars table; columns make, model, year
Toyota.nze.2006
nissan.march.2010

Lorry table; columns make, model, year
ford.hhh.2006
toyota.gggg.2010

Comment: Bind them with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

For all 2015 bmw, audio, mercedes benz

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE year = 2015 AND (choice = 'ford' OR choice = 'audio' OR choice = 'mercedes benz')`

Use `"` and interpolate variables with `{$variable}` to define strings in PHP.

Comment: You may iterate all post fields and concat to the query string. This is easiest using a framework like laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build up the WHERE clause using a loop. I would recommend that you look at binding values to prevent SQL injection.

In effect, you will need a query which is doing something like

```
$baseQuery = "SELECT * 
FROM <table>
WHERE (`year` = $year[0] and `choice` = $choice[0])";
```

as a base query

You'll then probably need to ascertain how many additional rows there are, and if there are more than one then add to your base query so you could do something like;

```
$additional = '';

if (count($year) > 1) {

    foreach($year as $key=>$y) {
        if($key > 0) { 
        $additional .= $query[0] . "(`year` = $year[$key] and `choice` = $choice[$key])";
       }
    }
}
```

If you stick this above the $baseQuery and then append the $additional to the base query;

```
 $additional = '';

if (count($year) > 1) {

    foreach($year as $key=>$y) { 
        if($key > 0) {
        $additional .= $query[0] . "(`year` = $year[$key] and `choice` = $choice[$key])";
        }
    }
}

$baseQuery = "SELECT * 
FROM <table>
WHERE (`year` = $year[0] and `choice` = $choice[0]) " . $additional;
```

Comment: In the query: 
$baseQuery = "SELECT * 
FROM <table>
WHERE (`year` = $year[0] and `choice` = $choice[0]) " . $additional;

I think you misunderstood what i'm trying to do.
The tables are cars and lorry.
$choice will store the selected value from the dropdown.

And what about <table> in the statement baseQuery? My table should be one of the values in drop down.

Comment: Please provide some sample data in your original question.

Comment: I added it
In fact what i need to know is how to use the selected value in the sql statement SELECT * FROM $table

Can PHP variable $table be used as a table name in an SQL query?

Comment: To grab data from two separate tables you'll have to do a `union` or have separate queries. It would be simpler if you had one table with a vehicle type column.

Comment: in fact i want to use this logic; having 2 different tables
can you help me with that?